# PrimeFaces Datatable how to refresh correctly inputText and selectBooleanCheckbox inside

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a some `p:inputText` and `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` inside few columns of a `p:dataTable`. When I filter the list of elements using the header filter of the column to save only few elements to database, the header filters are cleaned. So I solved this problem using `filterValue="#{bean.map.field}"` in `p:column`, but when the `p:dataTable` is updated the editable components like `p:inputText` and `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` are not updated correctly, however if I change the filters the `p:dataTable` updates and the editable fields shows the correct values, but only if I change the filters. How can I solve?

That's my xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable id="trips-table" widgetVar="trips-table" first="#{tripList.tablePageIdx}" rowIndexVar="tripIdx" rowKey="#{trip.id}" var="trip" value="#{tripList.trips}" filteredValue="#{tripList.filteredTrips}" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="top" rows="15" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {Exporters} {RowsPerPageDropdown}">
                                <!-- ManyColumns -->
    <p:column headerText="#{text['trip.notes']}" filterBy="#{trip.notes}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterValue="#{tripList.tableFilters.notes}" sortBy="#{trip.notes}">
        <p:inputText value="#{trip.notes}" title="#{trip.notes}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

filteredTrips in TripList (bean) is defined as `List<Map>` and tableFilters is defined as `Map tableFilters = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: Please provide an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example